# Error 500 Internal Server Error PHP Script write to CSV

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, t-sql, csv

I am attempting to run a report for instances in the DB for the last month. This will then save the results as a .CSV file.
The problem I am encountering is that with this script I am getting an Internal Server Error 500.
If I use a WHERE clause on the query to filter out data, I am not getting this issue so I know the query and the function to create the .CSV file are working to some degree. I get a fully populated .CSV file. However without an additional WHERE clause, the file appears to be populating to a point with the majority of the data, but then appears to restart and the resulting file only contains about 1/8 of the overall data.
I am expecting 40K+ rows of data in the monthly .csv
function createFile(){

/*
        * This method will be used to create the csv file
        */

```
    //-----Connection to DB-----//

    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $this->dbLogin, "PWD" => $this->dbLogin);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $this->serverName, $connectionInfo)or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));    

    //-----SQL Query-----//

    $getList = sqlsrv_query($conn, $this->queryString, array(), $this->options)or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));            

    //-----File creation-----//

    $fp = fopen("../" . $this->portal . "/" . $this->folder . "/" . $this->fileName . ".csv", 'w+');

    // //-----Add in first row that contains the column titles-----//



    fputcsv($fp, $this->headerArray);

    fclose($fp);    

    // // // -----Add data to the csv file-----//

    $fp = fopen("../" . $this->portal . "/" . $this->folder . "/" . $this->fileName . ".csv", 'a+');
    $data = array();
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getList,  SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

    $data['id'] = $row['id'];
    $data['fullname'] = $row['fullname'];
    $data['profile'] = $row['profile'];
    $data['starttime'] = date_format($row['starttime'],'D jS M Y  G:i');
    $data['endtime'] = date_format($row['endtime'], 'D jS M Y  G:i');
    $endTime = date_format($row['endtime'], 'U');
    $startTime = date_format($row['starttime'], 'U');
            if($startTime == null || $startTime == ""){
        $startTime = $endTime;
     }
    $diff  = ($endTime - $startTime); 
        $data['duration']  = round($diff/3600).gmdate(":i:s", $diff);
            $data['hour'] =date_format($row['starttime'] ,'G');
    $data['ref'] = $row['ref'];
    $data['endType'] = $row['endType'];
    $data['problem'] = $row['problem'];
    $data['solution'] = $row['solution'];
    $data['type'] = $row['type'];

    fputcsv($fp, array_values($data));
    }       

    fclose($fp); 

    sqlsrv_close($conn);    
}
```

The above is the function used in my class file to create the .csv file. The query I'm using is.

```
$this->queryString ="SELECT A.id

      ,B.firstname + ' ' + B.lastname AS fullname

      ,B.location
      ,A.profile
      ,A.siteid
      ,A.accountnumber
      ,A.starttime
      ,A.endtime
      ,A.ref
      ,A.endType
      ,A.problem
      ,A.solution
      ,A.type

       FROM trend.report A
       LEFT JOIN users.profile B
      ON A.empId = B.id

      WHERE DATEDIFF( M, A.endtime, GETDATE()) = 0
      ORDER BY A.endtime DESC";
```

If I add for example

```
 AND A.profile ='exampleProfile'
```

I still get 20K+ rows, but I get a compeleted .CSV file.

Anything glaringly obvious with this? Or could be be due to the number of rows/ time taken to execute the script?
Thanks

Comment: A 500 error usually generates entries in the error log of the webserver

Answer (score 1):

Do you execute this from the command line or browser?

1) If you do this in your browser, you might reach a HTTP timeout (often 30s). You can raise it but it would be better to execute the PHP script from command line

```
<?php
 set_time_limit(600); // 10 minutes
```

2) You reach your memory limit. Try to raise it on the first line of your PHP file:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

Actual top depends on server, the server should also accept setting memory_limit through php files. Otherwise you can config it straight on the webserver.

Comment: Thankyou for your response, Trying these out now.
But what would explain the script from starting the file again and only getting a little of the way through? I would expect the remaining result when it starts again but im getting the first few rows back. Memory limit perhaps?